# Почему не работает recurse_copy()?

Tags: php

```
mkdir($forum, 0700);
recuse_copy('example',$forum);
```

Не работает, в чем ошибка ?

Comment: а такая функция разве есть? помоему нет такой функции

Comment: а вы не могли бы подробнее описать проблему?Я имею ввиду,вы не могли бы ошибку показать?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
function copyFile($dirname,$dirdestination) 
{ 
    $dir = opendir($dirname);

    while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) 
    { 
        if(is_file($dirname."/".$file)) 
        { 
            copy($dirname."/".$file, $dirdestination."/".$file); 
        } 
        if(is_dir($dirname."/".$file) && 
        $file != "." && 
        $file != "..") 
        { 
            if(!is_dir($dirdestination."/".$file)) 
            { 
                mkdir($dirdestination."/".$file); 
            } 
            copyFile("$dirname/$file","$dirdestination/$file"); 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($dir); 
} 
?>
```